# Sendgrid API test returns bad request with no reason

Tags: email, sendgrid

I wanna test sendgrid API using a command from their official docs.

```
 curl -i --request POST --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send --header 'Authorization: Bearer MY_API_KEY' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": “some@gmail.com"}]}],"from": {"email": "some@else.com"},"subject": "Hello, World!","content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "Howdy!"}]}'
```

I'm getting this error:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Request","field":null,"help":null}]}
```

The API key is brand new, I just created it. It has full access. What's wrong? I bet the docs is outdated and either the endpoint or its parameters or both have been changed.

Anyway, any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

nm the data format is wrong. subject should be in "to" section. the example was outdated